# linux c: When do I need "clone" function instead of "fork"?

Tags: c, linux, process, fork, clone

The man page says:

> Unlike fork(2), clone() allows the child process to share parts of its
>   execution context with the calling process, such as  the  memory 
>   space, the  table  of  file  descriptors, and the table of signal
>   handlers. (Note that on this manual page, "calling process" normally
>   corresponds to "parent process".  But see the description of
>   CLONE_PARENT below.)

What I don't understand is "the  table  of  file  descriptors", because when I use fork, the child can of course write to the FD that's opened by father process, like I tested below:

```
$ cat myfork.cpp
#include<fcntl.h>
#include<unistd.h>
int main()
{
    int f1=open("./test.txt",O_CREAT|O_RDWR);
    pid_t id=fork();
    if(id>0)//father
    {
    sleep(1);
    for(size_t i=0;i<10;++i)
    {
        sleep(2);
        write(f1,"father write1\n",14);
    }
    }
    else//child
    {
    for(size_t i=0;i<10;++i)
    {
        sleep(2);
        write(f1,"child write1\n",13);
    }
    }
    close(f1);
    return 0;
}
```

The running result is:

```
$ cat test.txt
child write1
father write1
child write1
father write1
child write1
father write1
child write1
father write1
child write1
father write1
child write1
father write1
child write1
father write1
child write1
father write1
child write1
father write1
child write1
father write1
```

Both process can write to same file in turn, so can I understand that "forked" process can also share fd table? Then what's the necessity of "clone" function?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The table is not shared, it's copied. After a `fork`, each process has its own file descriptor table.

To implement things like threads, you need the table to be shared such that changes to the file descriptor are seen in both scheduling entities.

Comment: To put it more simply, `clone` is really useful only to thread implementors (the few people writing libraries like POSIX threads, not the many people *using* POSIX threads)